# One time use (single run) program. How to implement

Tags: android

I'm probably going to get flamed for asking this question and told it's a repeat but I don't believe it really is.  I have read every post even remotely related to this issue I could find but none of them addresses the problem I'm having.  I find it hard to believe that I'm the only person who has ever been faced with this issue so let me try to explain it in some detail.  I have an application that needs to get the user's location at the very beginning of the app.  I don't care after that point whether or not the user's location changes, it's only the first location that is important.  Based on that location and the answers to several more questions that are obtained from multiple screens, I reach a solution.  It is fine for the user to pause/resume the application at any point before the solution is reached and to navigate back and forth between the screens that lead to that result.  However, once the solution has been reached it is not permitted to review any of the previous screens.  Imagine, for the purposes of this question that doing so would result in something horrible happening so it is completely forbidden.  Also, once the solution has been displayed, it is also forbidden for the user to display the solution again once he has closed the application by pressing the home button.  The reasons don't matter, these are the parameters of the question.  Given this, once the user leaves the application for any reason after a solution has been given the only reasonable thing to do if the user reopens the application is start over from the very beginning.  There is also almost never a reason the user would want to reuse the application twice in one day so he should not be returned to the starting screen on leaving the application.  I don't care if the application remains active in the background or not as long as these parameters are met.  How could I do this?

I have tried several of the suggested methods and the one that comes closest is this:

```
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
            thisActivity.this.finish();
```

However, it seems to restart the app before closing which would leave me with an old, obsolete user location when the app is reopened.  I would appreciate any pointers or thoughts on how to deal with this scenario.

Comment: You have to track your progress. If you are in step x/y and pause the app, save your progress, inputs and stuff, when the app comes back you restore step x/y. When step y/y is reached, clear the progress so the app starts with the first input again....

Comment: This really doesn't address my main issue. How do I force the application to restart from scratch once the user has closed it? Moving back and forth during the application is not a problem, I just can't figure out how to prevent the user from seeing the final solution again once he leaves the application and forcing it to start again from scratch instead.

Comment: On application start/resume check a flag in shared preferences. If it's set to true, start new and set the flag to false, if it's set to false, restore your progress. When you show the solution, set the flag in the shared preferences to true. That's what I meant with tracking progress...

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it doesn't help me. I already know how to tell when the program needs to restart; I need to know how to actually do it. I haven't found a way to close a program and force it to restart. You are telling me what to do, I need to know how to do it.

Comment: if(flagIsSet) showFirstViewAndStartProcedure() else showLastViewUserVisitedAndContinueWithEverything() ... you don't have to close a program. Just check the state in onResume...

Comment: Your application is not closing when the user presses the Home button. The user must press the back button to force the application to close. You can just clear all data in onResume(). The only drawback is that this method is also called when a phone call is taken.

Comment: That helps. I've been programming for quite a while using iOS but I'm still fairly new to android. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 for testing and the Back Button isn't very obvious on it, at least to me.  I was completely ignoring that key.  I'm going to need to do some testing but I think this has pointed me in the right direction.  As I said, I know what needs to be done, I just couldn't quite grasp how to accomplish it. I'm ok with the onResume() thing, if the user closes the app for any reason he must start over from scratch, that was one of my parameters.